# Microsoft Edge cannot read local files with AJAX method of JQuery

Tags: microsoft-edge, jquery-ajaxq

I'm creating a program to access local files using the ajax method of JQuery.

This program is working correctly in IE11 and older version but failing in Microsoft Edge browser.

It is showing the 'Network error' for the same and going to error section in Microsoft Edge.

Can someone let me know the workaround for the same?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    BrandAllMenu();
});

function BrandAllMenu() {
           var  xmlPath = "branding.xml";
           $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: xmlPath,
                async: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function () {
                    alert("in");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status + " Response text : "+ jqXHR.responseText);
                    alert("Menu XML test status: " + textStatus);
                    alert("Menu XML: " + errorThrown)
                }
            });



      }

</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you opening the file right from you file system or through a local web server? Maybe allowing localhost loopback through about:flags will help.

Comment: I am trying to access files from local file system. It was working fine till IE11, but now failing in MS Edge.

Comment: I have a very similar problem: `$.getJSON("file:///C:/Web/data.json")` just does not work, while it's working nice in Firefox.